# Post photo on Facebook page doesn't work

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't post a photo on a facebook page with my facebook app (V 2.11). My app has the manage_pages e publish_pages permissions. I have a page token too. Post text works well. If I use a image url from my domain the post doesn't work if I use a image url from another domain (eg: tripadvisor) the post works. My domain has a SSL DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA.

This is my code:

```
def PostPhotoFB(photo, title, link, text , fb_access_token, fb_page_id, desc):

    facebook_data = {'url': photo,
        'access_token': fb_access_token,
        'caption': text,
    }

    facebook_request = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + fb_page_id + "/photos"
    response_facebook = requests.post(facebook_request, data=facebook_data)

    if response_facebook.status_code == 200:
        return json.loads(response_facebook.text)['id']
    else:
        return ""
```

with an image in my server I get **400** and

> "(#324) Missing or invalid image
>   file","type":"OAuthException","code":324

I use Jpg or PNG image.

this is a exemple url "https://www.stbrun.com/static/img_locale/24/biciclette.jpg"

I don't understand. Can you help me please? Thanks a lot

Comment: So something about your own image URLs seems to be the issue then. Seems only natural/common-sense-y that you would give us an actual example URL to check then ...

Comment: Sorry, you are right. This is a url : www.stbrun.com/static/img_locale/24/biciclette.jpg

Comment: But you did actually include the protocol, yes?

Comment: ops... https://www.stbrun.com/static/img_locale/24/biciclette.jpg

Comment: Checking the image URL in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ gives _“Curl Error : SSL_CACERT SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate”_ Your certificate chain is incomplete, https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.stbrun.com

Answer (score 0):

Using the graph api, you can post like this:

```
import facebook
def main():
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='your_user_access_token', 
       version='2.8')
    #if version 2.8 shows error use 2.6
    attachment =  {
        'name': 'Link name'
        'link': 'https://www.example.com/',
        'caption': 'Check out this example',
        'description': 'This is a longer description of the attachment',
        'picture': 'https://www.example.com/thumbnail.jpg'
    }

    graph.put_wall_post(message='Check this out...', 
       attachment=attachment, profile_id='your_page_id')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you leave the profile_id blank, it will default to your profile. In the attachment dictionary, you can leave the extra fields that you don't need. First you need to install fackbook-sdk:

pip install facebook-sdk